# Arguments in a method are not compiling

Tags: java

I'm just trying to create short java program to ask for an int from a user then add 3 to that int and display it. For some reason I am getting the syntax all wrong.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {


    public int attempt (int b) {
            return 3+entry;
    }


    int r = attempt(entry);

    public static void main (String[] args){
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println ("Enter single digit int ");
            int entry = keyboard.nextInt();


            System.out.println("Your number is " + entry);
            System.out.println("Your number is " );

            System.out.println("The final result is " + r);

            }


}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {


// this function should be static
public static int attempt (int b) {
        //b for entry, since b is the name of the variable
        return 3 + b;
}


public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println ("Enter single digit int ");
        int entry = keyboard.nextInt();

        //put this in your main function
        int r = attempt(entry);
        System.out.println("Your number is " + entry);
        System.out.println("Your number is " );

        System.out.println("The final result is " + r);

        }
}
```

i think you should work through some java tutorials...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call a non-static function or reference a non-static variable from a static function.

So basically you have to write

```
public static int attempt ....
static int r = ...
```

The problem is that static methods operate on the class test, and non-static methods operate on instances of the class test.